Closed unit ball is weakly closed - I didn't use the assumption that $X$ is Banach
Folland $5.48$ asks us to prove that:
Let $X$ be a Banach space, the closed unit ball is weakly closed. Here is my proof:
Claim:
$$
B = \bigcap_{f\in X^{*},\hspace{0.1 cm} ||f||\leq 1}\{x\in X: |f(x)|\leq 1\}.
$$
Pf. Note that the zero functional is a functional on $X$ with norm equal or less than $1$, hence the right-hand side is not an empty intersection.
Now take $x\in B$, for any $f\in X^\star$ such that $||f||\leq 1$, we have
$$
|f(x)|\leq ||f||\cdot ||x||\leq 1\cdot 1 = 1.
$$
$x$ is in the RHS. Take $x\in$ RHS, if $x = 0$ then $x\in B$. Otherwise, by the Hahn-Banach theorem, there exists $f\in X^{*}$, $||f|| = 1$ and $f(x) = ||x||$. $f$ satisfies the requirements to be included in the intersection and hence $|f(x)|\leq 1$, $||x||\leq 1$, $x\in B$.
Now we have expressed $B$ as the intersection of weakly closed sets, and hence $B$ is weakly closed.
I noticed that I didn't use the fact that $X$ is a Banach space in my proof. Is it that the conclusion holds for a non-Banach space, or is there something wrong with my proof?
Thank you!

There’s nothing wrong. The proof is fine.

Oh so whether the normed space is Banach or not, the closed unit ball is always weakly closed? @DavidGao

Yes, that is correct.

Thank you!@DavidGao

Every convex and closed subset of a locally convex space is weakly closed.

There is nothing wrong with your proof. This is one of those cases where one needs to distinguish closed from complete. The two things are the same when considered inside a complete space, but not otherwise.

I agree that the two things are the same when $X$ is complete. Do you mean that a closed unit ball of a non-Banach space might not be complete? Or we can distinguish weakly closedness and completeness in a non-Banach space?

@Coco The closed unit ball is complete iff the space if complete. But that is completeness under the norm. If we are talking about completeness under the uniform structure corresponding to the weak topology, then even the unit ball of a Banach space is not necessarily complete.

Thank you! @DavidGao
